# Is there a reason why this year's Winter Bash site prevents crawling?

Tags: support, winter-bash, robots, winter-bash-2018

This year's Winter Bash site has [`robots.txt`](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/robots.txt) which prevents the *whole*<sup>1</sup> site from being crawled.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Is there a reason why `robots.txt` was added to this year's WB site?

<sup>1</sup>The main page is [crawled and archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20181213140213/https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/) on the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Google's spider was hitting it... A lot...

This was causing a lot of unnecessary load on the server. Best to just block the bots so as to let real people enjoy it.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the response! Would it be possible to *only* allow Wayback Machine to crawl it (maybe after the whole event ends)?

Answer (score 4):

There are possibly 2 other explanations for this (apart from what Shog mentioned already):

- It is to prevent using search engines to answer searches about *secret hats*.
- It's a way to implement the equivalent of ***I hate hats*** for search engines, whereas:

  - they seem to not have a choice to change their preference.
  - the default for them is the opposite of the default (= ***I like hats***) for regular SE users.