# What will happen when Winter Bash is over?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018, rankings, winterbash-leaderboard

Tomorrow (January 2nd, 2019) is the day that Winter Bash will be gone.

So I am thinking: Will there be some sort of a final ranking page anywhere?

It would be nice so I don't need to keep going to [the Leaderboard](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) every day to see my rank.

If there isn't going to be anything like that, what should I do to see my final rank on Winter Bash?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nothing will change at the Winter Bash page (https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com) after Jan 1st. The main WB page and the leaderboard will display as is until the SE team redirects it to the [Stack Overflow Contest site](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/) later in the year.

The pages will stop updating after Jan 1st since no new hats can be earned and the ranking shown on the leaderboard after then will be your final ranking.

After the whole WB page is removed, you won’t be able to see your ranking (similarly, you aren’t able to see your last year’s WB ranking).

---

However, hats on your profile **will be removed on Jan 1st** and you can’t change your hats after that.

[image]

---

There will also be a wrap-up blog post usually published 6-8 days after WB ends. (Past blog posts here: [2017](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/10/farewell-winter-bash-2017/), [2016](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/09/say-farewell-to-winter-bash-2016/), [2015](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/01/06/winter-bash-2015-hats-off/), [2014](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/01/06/so-long-winter-bash-2014/), [2013](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/01/03/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up/) & [2012](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/01/08/boxing-day/))

#### So, take lots of screenshots while you still have your hats!

Answer (score 3):

For most years, the final ranking pages have been archived on the Wayback Machine. I [couldn't find working links for 2018 though](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/*), probably because, as @Panda pointed out, [there were some problems with Google's crawler](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320666/295232) back then.

| Year | Leaderboard (site overview) | Network-wide leaderboard |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2013 | [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140209180136/https://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) | final leaderboard not available |
| 2014 | [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150509210612/https://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/) | [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150909222301/https://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) |
| 2015 | [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160316190603/https://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/) | [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20161024141151/https://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) |
| 2016 | [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170701180918/http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com:80/leaderboard) | [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170629003620/http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) |
| 2017 | [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180110150709/https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) | final leaderboard not available |
| 2018 | not available | not available |
| 2019 | [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200115161630/https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) | [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200115151602/https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) |
| 2020 | [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123150709/https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) | [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123142540/https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) |
| 2021 | [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220519084855/https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) | [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220126211741/https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network) |

Comment: If you happen to wonder, [here's why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320664/is-there-a-reason-why-this-years-winter-bash-site-prevents-crawling) 2018's pages aren't available in the Wayback Machine.